# Fix point of an isometry under certain conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, isometry

I'd like to show the following statement:

Let $V$ be a euclidean vector space with finite dimension, $B(V) := \{\phi: V \rightarrow V | \phi$ is an isometry$\}$, $\phi \in B(V)$. Assume there exists a $\psi \in B(V)$ s.t. $\psi^{-1} \circ \phi \circ \psi \in O(V)$, where $O(V)$ is the orthogonal group. Show that $\phi$ has a fixed point.

Any hints?

Comment: I don't understand your conditions; isn't $B(V)=O(V)$?

Comment: @ArnaudD. $B(V)$ is the group of _affine_ isometries, $O(V)$ the group of linear isometries. [Nontrivial result used: every isometry of a Euclidean space is affine.]

Comment: Hint: every $\vartheta \in O(V)$ has a fixed point.

Comment: Ah I thought the isometries were supposed to be linear. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks, but how do we know that an orthogonal matrix has always an eigen value 1?

Comment: Never mind, it's a linear map, so trivially there's a fixed point for an orthogonal map, sorry!

Comment: For those who stumbled on this page looking for the nontrivial result mentionned, [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2202779/92038) is the proof